# select values in column reverse order

Tags: mysql

I need to select the records wit columns in reverse order table structure.
For Example,
If My table struture is like this

```
class   name        rank  
------  ----------  ------
A       Nija             2
D       cruz             3
B       Antony           4
C       silverster       5
A       febin            1
```

means I want the result as

```
  rank  name        class 
------  ----------  ------
     2  Nija        A     
     3  cruz        D     
     4  Antony      B     
     5  silverster  C     
     1  febin       A
```

you can say that select the columns like rank,name,class. But My Table columns will increase in dynamically. I want the result if my table contains any number of columns but the result should be in reverse of the table structure. Here i ll select all columns only.

Comment: *My Table columns will increase in dynamically*  Why are you adding columns dynamically to your table?  This sounds like a design flaw.  You should not need to add new columns dynamically to a table.  Can you elaborate on your current design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SET @myval=(select group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)from (
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'Table1'
order by ORDINAL_POSITION desc) a);

SET @strsql=CONCAT('select ',@myval,' from Table1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @strsql; 
EXECUTE stmt;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/196d9/41)

Comment: If i use this ,it results the same table columns in other Database also how can i restrict that?

Comment: I have the same table sample in two different DBs named DTRESS & DTREEHASH. Ur Query returns the Column names DTREES.sample And DTREEHASH.sample. I just Want DTREE.sample Columns only. How can i achive that?

Comment: check the updated query which will give you the comma separated list of columns in reverse order.

Comment: pls check the latest query for the complete solution.

Comment: should i use procedure? im trying to make one single query.

Comment: you have to use in procedure

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do simply

```
SELECT rank, name, class FROM table_name;
```

Comment: i dont know the column names.. It may append dynamically